# Using qsys2.qcmdexc but switching user

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I have an internal website where I am trying to user some existing RPG/CL code from an iSeries server.  I would like to occasionally run iSeries jobs on behalf of a logged in user.  The connection to the iSeries I am using however is running under a user name like "appuser" specifically setup for the application (that has ODBC read only access) over the SQL connection.  The problem that I run into is that much of the security/logging that happens on the iSeries uses the job user to stamp records all over the place and that user is the name of the application rather than the user logged into it.

I can get commands to work using qsys2.qcmdexc but I need a way to switch the user to the appropriate "real user" from the iSeries (I have their username in the web application).  The only idea I have come up with is to have a CL program that does a submit job of the command string and pass the real user in as the user.

Are there any better options to change the user for a job so I can run things interactively as them on via the SQL connection?  Or is my best bet to do the submit job?

Comment: Best would probably be to change your logging function to use the currentUser rather than applicationName (or jobUser). It's not a good choice to ignore currentUser if it really is `security logging` that is intended.

Comment: This is a relatively large "off the shelf" software package so I wouldn't want to modify that much software... it uses the SDS structure (user/terminal)  and the logging is really just things like changed/created user on records but for tracking things down is useful.

Comment: There should only be single function (perhaps called from many places), but not much you can do if a package isn't rational.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article by Shannon O'Donnel with a program that can swap a user profile.  I've used it with success:

http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo071703-story02.html

Comment: Some testing should be done to verify that the profile swapping doesn't interfere with the swapping that already happens in the database server and (possibly) the existing application upon connection,

Comment: This looks interesting, the thing I notice is that is looks like it works with password of length 10 which does not over the 128 length of password level 2.  I'll look into it a bit more, perhaps I can adapt it.

Comment: You did see the date on the article, as well as the APIs used, right?  Why not adapt them and publish the updated code?

Comment: @clutton Check more current documentation. The API handles 128-char pass-phrases fine, but it necessarily became more complex at the same time.